# Convert string[] To Decimal[],int[],float[] .double[] in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight

```
string[] txt1 = new string[]{"12","13"};

this.SetValue(txt1, v => Convert.ChangeType(v, typeof(decimal[]), null));
```

it throws an error -   Object must implement IConvertible.

I also want a code to convert string[] To Decimal[],int[],float[] .double[]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't convert a string[] straight to a decimal[] like that - all the elements have to be individually converted to the new type. Instead, you can use [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx)

```
string[] txt1 = new string[]{"12","13"};
decimal[] dec1 = Array.ConvertAll<string, decimal>(txt1, Convert.ToDecimal);
```

And similarly using `Convert.ToInt32`, `Convert.ToSingle`, `Convert.ToDouble` for the `Converter<TInput,TOutput>` argument to produce int[], float[], double[], substituting in the correct type arguments to ConvertAll

EDIT: As you're using silverlight, which doesn't have ConvertAll, you'll have to do it manually:

```
decimal[] dec1 = new decimal[txt1.Length];
for (int i=0; i<txt1.Length; i++) {
    dec1[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(txt1[i]);
}
```

Comment: is this will give me the result decimal[]

Comment: Yup - the return value from ConvertAll will be a decimal[]

Comment: Accept this is there any other way as  convertAll is not supported at my end

Comment: i AM RUNNING .NET 3.5 VERSION

Comment: I didn't check it with a compiler - you need to specify the type arguments explicity, I've edited my post to show this

Comment: Is there any other way as i am not getting the property ConvertAll of Array

Comment: Try specifying the namespace directly - System.Array.ConvertAll. As you can see from the MSDN page, that method has been in there since .NET 2.0

Comment: Thanks coop it works if i take  a simple class project but this i wanted in the classlibray which is in the  silverlight aap..So in this it doesnot display ConvertAll..So please can you show me other direction to this..Thanks in advance.